# Getting data inside p tags as a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a website that displays some products, and when I go to the page of each product, there are 3 values, item number, sku and brand that i want t obtain in a single row for 1 product, and row wise for each of the products by creating a loop.
My attempt at extracting this data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
def cpap_spider(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll("h2", {"class":"product-name"}):
        href=link.find("a")['href']
        each_item(href)
            
        
        

def each_item(item_url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(item_url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    mpn=soup.find("div", {"class":"product-view-sublock basic-information"})
    name= mpn.find("p")
    mpn_value=mpn.text
    if mpn:
        
        print(mpn_value)
    else:
        print("not found")
   
   
    
            
cpap_spider("https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/pediatric-wheelchairs/")
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: i wanted to get the data as a table where the headers are sku, item number and brand, and for each product the entries are filled row wise. Even a displayed output without headers would do, not necessarily an excel/csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests, json, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/pediatric-wheelchairs/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

p_links = [i["data-link"] for i in soup.find("ul", {"id":"products-list"}).find_all("li",class_=["openlink","item"])]

data = []
for prod_url in p_links:
    print(prod_url)
    temp = {"Product URL": prod_url}
    prod_res = requests.get(prod_url, headers = headers)
    prod_soup = BeautifulSoup(prod_res.text, "html.parser")

    for p in prod_soup.find("div", class_="basic-information").find_all("p"):
        if "item" in p.text.lower(): temp["item"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
        elif "brand" in p.text.lower(): temp["brand"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
        elif "sku" in p.text.lower(): temp["sku"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
    
    data.append(temp)
    time.sleep(1)

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

with open("data.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Output:

```
Product URL,item,sku,brand
https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/ziggo-lightweight-wheelchair-for-kids-with-pop-off-wheels/,83017,ZG1200,Circle Specialty
https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/excel-kidz-pediatric-wheelchair/,34872,MDS806140PD,Medline
...
...
```